# Ajax Error: 200 Response Code

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm using the [jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin to handle a form submission with Ajax:

```
$('.login-form').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log('Success!');
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log('There was an error:');
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

After submission, the ajax returns an error with a status of "200". This is the JSON-formatted response:

```
{
    "success": false, 
    "heading": "The following errors were encountered", 
    "message": "<ul><li>The existing username and/or password you submitted are not valid</li></ul>"
}
```

I ran that through [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/), and it returned as valid.

In Chrome's Network tab, the response is returned as type `application/json`.

So why is ajax returning "error" rather than "success"?

jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: What's the question?  What is it doing that you don't expect?

Comment: `console.log(data.responseText)`

Comment: Some services are broken and don't use status codes to show an error status.  It looks to me like you just need to check the `success` key.

Comment: Make sure EE has the template type set to JavaScript (assuming the response is in a template)

Comment: @BarbaraLaird It's returning an Ajax "error" rather than an Ajax "success" (please note that Ajax "success" is different from the "success" value inside the JSON response).

Comment: So, it is going into the error: function ()?  Because a status of 200 is OK.

Comment: @BrianLitzinger How would that help?

Comment: @kgrote i think he was trying to clarify your response. Add the code i gave you above so that we can see exactly what the server is returning. Also, add two more parameters to the error handler and log them too. The second is textstatus, the third is error text.

Comment: @kgrote So what is the error?

Comment: @kgrote I'm trying to clarify, because I don't understand the question.  You say it's returning a status of 200, which is the OK response code (not an error response).  Then, you said it's returning an ajax "error".  What do you mean by that?  Is your problem that the error function is being called instead of the success function?  Or is something else happening?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird That means that `error` callback is called (even though response is 200), i.e. there's an error on client side. Possibly due to JSON parsing (most probable) or maybe because this plugin (which I don't know) throws it.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the JSON `message` key had a line break inside it, which for some reason caused an error:

```
{
    "success": false, 
    "heading": "The following errors were encountered", 
    "message": "<ul><li>The existing username and/or password you submitted are not valid</li>
</ul>"
}
```

I wouldn't think line breaks inside a string would matter, but I guess they do...